# Why does my old JavaScript tool Repeating Elements in an Array and How to fix?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Here is the input that should be converted to JSON format as given below.
`{RS0004036}:{0;3}:{0000003AB;0000003BC}_{RS0004036}:{3;3}:{0000003DE;0000003FG}_{RS0004036}:{1;2}:{0000003HI;0000003JK}`
The code should read the above input, will create a JSON return string as follows. The returning JSON will return store which will be only one value of the index 0 of the input string and will not repeat as `partList`. Target JSON should be like this.

```
"storeList": [
    {
        "store": "RS0004036",
        "partList": [
            {
                "part": "0000003AB",
                "partSub": "0000003BC",
                "qtyOnHand": "0",
                "qtyMinMax": "3"
            },
                   {
                "part": "0000003DE",
                "partSub": "0000003FG",
                "qtyOnHand": "3",
                "qtyMinMax": "3"
            },
            {
                "part": "0000003HI",
                "partSub": "0000003JK",
                "qtyOnHand": "1",
                "qtyMinMax": "2"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Here is my code:

```js
const hdr_str = '{RS0004036}:{1;2}:{0000003AB;0000003BC}_{RS0004036}:{0;3}:{0000003DE;0000003FG}_{RS0004036}:{3;3}:{0000003HI;0000003JK}';;

var storeList = {};
var partList = [];
storeList.partList = partList;

//Processing
const partsDataEntries = hdr_str.split('_');

for (var index = 0; index < partsDataEntries.length; index++) {
  const element = partsDataEntries[index].slice(1, -1);
  console.log('element0' + element);
  if (element != '') {
    const storepart = element.split(':');
    const storeId = storepart[0].slice(1, -1);
    const [qtyOnHand, qtyMinMax] = element.split(':')[1].split(';');
    
    console.log("element.split(':')[1]" + element.split(':')[1]);
    const qtyOH = qtyOnHand.substring(1, qtyOnHand.length);
    const qtyMM = qtyMinMax.substring(0, qtyMinMax.length - 1);
    const [partnum, partsub] = element.split(':')[2].split(';');
    
    const part = partnum.substring(1, partnum.length);
    storeList.storeId = storeId;
    
    partList = {
      "partnum": part,
      "partsub": partsub,
      "qtyOnHand": qtyOH,
      "qtyMinMax": qtyMM
    }
    
    storeList.partList.push(partList);
  }
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(storeList));
```

Somehow it is repeating the elements in my tool which has JavaScript engine which is very old and we cannot replace the tool. Can someone suggest how to fix it?

```json
{"partList":[{"partnum":"0000003AB","partsub":"0000003BC","qtyOnHand":"0","qtyMinMax":"3"}{"partnum":"0000003AB","partsub":"0000003BC","qtyOnHand":"0","qtyMinMax":"3"},{"partnum":"0000003AB","partsub":"0000003BC","qtyOnHand":"0","qtyMinMax":"3"}],"storeId":"RS0004036"}
```

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question.

Comment: One issue is, if you expect '"storeList": [' you should also declare storeList as an array [] and handle it like that

Comment: Your serialised format does not match the example JSON output. Eg. the `{1;2}` does not tally with the expected `qtyOnHand` and `qtyMinMax` in the output. Please provide clear and accurate data.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Fixed the typo. Thanks

Comment: What does the string look like if there's multiple stores?

Comment: It will be each store with part list. store 1 , part list , store 2, part list like that.

Comment: "*it is repeating the elements*" your code, as provided with the sample provided, doesn't appear to be doing this - it's easier to see what it's generating if you console.log the object rather than stringifying it, but it *appears* to be correct given the input - can you detail what's going wrong / what you're expecting vs what it's doing?   https://jsfiddle.net/xazbu3s2/

Comment: It smells like you are pushing the same object reference to storeList.partList but in this code you are clearly creating a new object each iteration.

Comment: @James Thanks. Can you please be specific?

Comment: I would expect this type of result if you had not assigned `partList` within the for loop, but you are, so it's not that.

Answer (score 1):

You could match and get all information to the reqired variables/properties.

```js
const
    data = '{RS0004036}:{1;2}:{0000003AB;0000003BC}_{RS0004036}:{0;3}:{0000003DE;0000003FG}_{RS0004036}:{3;3}:{0000003HI;0000003JK}',
    result = data
        .split('_')
        .reduce((r, s) => {
            const
                [store, qtyOnHand, qtyMinMax, part, partSub] = s.match(/[^\{\};:]+/g),
                item = { part, partSub, qtyOnHand, qtyMinMax };
            let o = r.find(o => o.store === store);
            if (o) o.partList.push(item);
            else r.push({ store, partList: [item] });
            return r;
        }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use string split/slice, use *named capturing groups* in a regular expression, eg:

```
const regex = /{(?<store>RS\d*)}:{(?<qtyOnHand>\d+);(?<qtyMinMax>\d+)}:{(?<part>.+);(?<partSub>.+)}/gm;
```

You can use this to parse each element and get the relevant property from the capturing groups result, eg

```
let storeName = m.groups["store"];
```

Updated snippet that extracts each part List and combines into a store list:

```js
const hdr_str = '{RS0004036}:{1;2}:{0000003AB;0000003BC}_{RS0004036}:{0;3}:{0000003DE;0000003FG}_{RS0004036}:{3;3}:{0000003HI;0000003JK}';;

let storeList = [];

//Processing
const partsDataEntries = hdr_str.split('_');

for (var element of partsDataEntries) {
  //console.log(element);

  const regex = /{(?<store>RS\d*)}:{(?<qtyOnHand>\d+);(?<qtyMinMax>\d+)}:{(?<part>.+);(?<partSub>.+)}/gm;
  let m;

  while ((m = regex.exec(element)) !== null) {

    let store = storeList.find(x => x.store == m.groups["store"]);
    if (store == null) {
      store = {
        "store": m.groups["store"],
        partList: []
      };
      storeList.push(store);
    }

    let part = {
      "part": m.groups["part"],
      "partSub": m.groups["partSub"],
      "qtyOnHand": m.groups["qtyOnHand"],
      "qtyMinMax": m.groups["qtyMinMax"]
    };
    store.partList.push(part);


  }
}
console.log(storeList);
console.log(JSON.stringify(storeList));
```